# Local Group Policy not shown in GPResult or RSOP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have applied a number of audit related policies through the Local Group Policy Editor on a non-domain machine.

Even though I can confirm from the Event Viewer logs that the events are being properly recorded, I cannot see those specific policies applied when I issue the below `gpresult /Scope Computer /v` or `rsop.msc`

Any thoughts?

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2, if it matters, thank you.

Comment: Use gpresult /h gpresult.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried, but still cannot find anything related with audit.